# File ended while scanning use of \@topnewpage

Tags: pdftex

I get this error while trying to compile the following code. I've already tried to delete .aux files. What else could it be the issue?

```
\documentclass[conference,harvard,brazil,english]{sbatex}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae}
%
% LaTeX2e class SBATeX
%
% Versão 1.0 alpha
%   Walter Fetter Lages
%   w.fetter@ieee.org
%
% Este arquivo cba_esq.tex é um esqueleto para geração do artigo para o CBA
%
% --------------------------------------------------
%
% Para compilar este exemplo use a seqüência de comandos:
%    
%     latex cba_esq
%     bibtex cba_esq
%     latex cba_esq
%     latex cba_esq
% 
% Para gerar um arquivo Postscript (.ps):
%
%     dvips -t a4 cba_esq
%
% Para gerar um arquivo Portable Document Format (.pdf):
%
%     dvips -Ppdf -t a4 cba_esq
%     ps2pdf -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.2 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 cba_esq.ps
%


\begin{document}

% CABEÇALHO

\title{Artigo Esqueleto}

\author{João da Silva}{jsilva@silva.com}
\address{Endereço do João e da Maria\\ Em algum lugar\\ Cidade, Estado, País}

\author{Joaquim Pereira}{jpereira@pereira.org}
\address{Endereço do Joaquim\\ Em algum lugar\\ Cidade, Estado, País}

\author[1]{Maria da Silva}{maria@pereira.org}

\author{Pedro Manoel}{pedro@pedro.com}
\address{Endereço do Pedro e do Rafael\\ Em algum lugar\\ Cidade, Estado, País}

\author{José Rodrigues}{jose@rodrigues}
\address{Endereço do José\\ Em algum lugar\\ Cidade, Estado, País}

\author[3]{Rafael Pires}{rafael@pires}


\twocolumn[

\maketitle

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    Enter abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Enter Keywords Here.}

\selectlanguage{brazil}
\begin{abstract} 
    Coloque o resumo aqui.
\end{abstract}




\selectlanguage{brazil}


% CONTRIBUIÇÃO

\section{Introdução}

    Esta é a introdução.

\subsection{Subseção}

    Esta é uma subseção.

\subsection{Outra Subseção}

    Esta é outra subseção.

\subsubsection{Subsubseção}

    Esta é uma subsubseção.

\section{Outra Seção}

    Esta é outra seção.

\section{Conclusões}

    Estas são as conclusões.

\section*{Agradecimentos}

    Estes são os agradecimentos.

% BIBLIOGRAFIA
\bibliography{exemplo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point to a link where the document class is available?

Comment: You have `\twocolumn[` so start the optional argument with `[` but never close it with `]`, hence the error message

Comment: I'm posting the file sbatex.cls.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/PaNkc0TSba/sbatex.html